# inserting data to postgres using python

Tags: python, postgresql

below is a sample of code that i am using to push data from one postgres server to another postgres server.  I am trying to move 28 Million records.  This worked perfectly with sql server to postgres, but now that it's postgres to postgres it is hanging on line
sourcecursor.execute('select * from "schema"."reallylargetable"; ')
it never reaches any of the other statements to get to the Iterator.

I get this message:

psycopg2.DatabaseError: out of memory for query result ad the select query statement.

```
#cursors for aiods and ili#
sourcecursor = sourceconn.cursor()
destcursor= destconn.cursor()


 #name of temp csv file
 filenme= 'filename.csv'



 #defenition that uses fetchmany to iterate through data in batch.  default 
value is in 10000#
def ResultIterator(cursor, arraysize=1000):
    'iterator using fetchmany and consumes less memory'
    while True:
       results = cursor.fetchmany(arraysize)
    if not results:
        break
    for result in results:
        yield result


 #set data for the cursor#

 print("start get data")
 #it is not going past the line below.  it errors at with out of memory for query result
 sourcecursor.execute('select * from "schema"."reallylargetable"; ')


 print("iterator")
 dataresults= ResultIterator(sourcecursor)
 *****do something with  dataresults *********
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change this line:

```
sourcecursor = sourceconn.cursor()
```

to name your cursor (use whatever name pleases you):

```
sourcecursor = sourceconn.cursor('mysourcecursor')
```

What this does is direct psycopg2 to open a postgresql server-side named cursor for your query.  Without a named cursor on the server side, psycopg2 attempts to grab all rows when executing the query.